# Google billing trial subscription error "Your transaction can't be completed"

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-subscription, android-billing

This is the current setup in Google Play console:

- Offer 1: 1W with 3d trial period
- Offer 2: 1M
- Offer 3: 1Y

When I request `queryProductDetails` I get next offers in `subscriptionOfferDetails` field:

- Offer 1: 1W + trial (2 pricing phases)
- Offer 2: 1W (this one I do not show to user)
- Offer 3: 1M
- Offer 4: 1Y

[image]

User selects trial plan and I call `launchBillingFlow` with Offer 1 purchase `offerToken`.
Google play payment window opens, there is trial info. User clicks subscribe and get next error:

> Your transaction can't be completed. To continue this transaction, use a different payment instrument or contact us

And `PurchasesUpdatedListener` returns code `BILLING_UNAVAILABLE 3`

[image]

Next cases works well

- buy trial with test google account and test google card
- buy production month and year subscription
- buy production week offer **without** trial

Only production trial subscription purchase returns this error.
I have tried several regions and card, asks colleagues from different countries with different devices, all of them can not buy trial subscription.
Real users cannot buy trial too.

Billing sdk version 6.1.0